# asp.net core identity tracking user open sessions

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-identity

We have a web application built with asp.net core, .net core 3.1, angular which uses asp.net core identity for user authentication management.
We have a need to implement the below scenario:

"If user A is logged in (this is an open session) and user B logs in with the same credentials (this is the 2nd concurrent session), after user B passes MFA, we will send an email to the email address of this customer to notify them that someone else just logged in. We will NOT end the session for the user A."

Our current implementation uses ASP.Net identity to authenticate users with Authentication Tickets being stored in cookies. Since authentication tickets are stored in cookies, the session is browser based, hence being able to track whether the user is logged in with an ongoing open session is not possible with this implementation.

I was leaning towards using custom store for storing auth tickets on server side with either database / redis, and then tracking token expiration thereby determining an existing ongoing session. Am I thinking along the right direction, or are there other mechanisms ? I would like some thougts and suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET Core Identity use Cookie authentication . That means when user B login in your application , application doesn't know whether user A is active , only next time userA send request with cookie to application , then application could check whether user A is active(authentication ticket is not expire ) and create a email response .  If user A doesn't send request to server , server won't know the state of user A since cookie is only sent with HTTP request .

You can use [asp.net core signalr](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/introduction?view=aspnetcore-3.1)  which enables server-side code to push content to clients instantly.